# How does using "not" differ from using a negative word?

Tags: word-choice, negation

How does using "not" differ from using a word with a negative prefix?

For example:

> It's **unwise** to vote down this question.
>   
> It's **not wise** to vote down this question

I know **semantically** *(or literally)*, *they're the same*. However, I want to know **grammatically**, how do they differ?

Comment: By "technically", do you mean that you want to know the grammatical terminology to describe the difference?

Comment: Yes. _according to the facts or exact meaning of something; strictly_ (from Google, 1st definition)

Comment: "Define technically" does not specifically mean "supply the grammatical terminology". "Technical" is actually a vague word in English, despite the fact that it suggests a kind of preciseness. Contrasting "semantically" with "technically" doesn't really make sense. A reader wonders, "What kind of preciseness do you have in mind?" BTW, referring someone to lmgtfy.com is a little bit insulting, as it suggests that I was careless and could easily have looked up the definition for myself. But if you look at the results, the definition doesn't mention grammatical terminology.

Comment: **Technically** they differ because one uses the prefix "un-" and the other uses the word "not". I'm pretty sure that this is **not** the "technical" answer you **want** but it is a **technical** one.

Comment: "Specifically" is not any better than "technically". You want "grammatically"

Comment: "Opionally"/commonly/regularly/usually/normally, if you asked a question that you've been thinking of it for so long, suddenly get a notification, open it and see criticisms of grammatical errors and accusations of offending someone instead of informative/helpful answers, how would you feel? Feel free to edit it if you think it's wrong but can still be understood by the public, since I've never proclaimed that I'm a professor.

Comment: Actually, in my first comment, I asked you for clarification. It was not a criticism. The clarification is needed to write a helpful answer.

Comment: By the way, anyone who have voted down this question please tell me why it's low quality because I want to know. Thanks!

Comment: I think it is now much improved with the change to *grammatically*. It was unclear what you wanted to know before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, **unwise** and **not wise** are nearly identical. **Unwise** is an adjective, while **not wise** is an adjective phrase.

To expand on the subject in general, you can add the prefix *un-* to many adjectives to form a negative form. Other examples are *unclear, unaware,* and *unpleasant*. Some words take a different prefix, such as *il-* in *illegitimate* (the opposite of *legitimate*), or *dis-* in *dishonored*, in which case the *un-* form does not exist or is very uncommon. Unfortunately most of these must be learned by rote (you have to memorize it for each word), as there isn't a good way to know without looking it up.

Comment: Can you simplify this part, _"To expand on the subject in general,"_, I don't understand what it means.

Comment: @XPMai I tried to clarify a little bit. What do you not understand specifically?

Comment: I don't understand the connotation. _How to expand a subject? What subject you referring?_

Comment: "To expand on a subject" means to explain more about a particular idea. The subject, or idea, that I am referring to is *negative adjectives*.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. It's **unwise** to vote down this question.
> 2. It's **not wise** to vote down this question

Adding a prefix like *un*- to an adjective is grammatically very different from using the adverb *not* to negate a verb phrase. The most important difference is that using *not* makes the whole clause negative, whereas a clause containing an adjective with *un*- will be positive unless there is some other word that makes it negative.

One way that we can show this is to put a negative question tag onto the end of the clause. Usually, when the we have a positive clause we find a negative question tag. If we have a negative clause, we see a positive tag:

- It's unwise to vote down this question, **isn't** it?
- It's not wise to vote down this question, **is** it?

If we use the opposite tags the sentences will either be marked (have an unusual meaning), or be ungrammatical:

- It's unwise to vote down this question, **is** it? (unusual/marked tag)
- It's not wise to vote down this question, **isn't** it? (ungrammatical)

Another effect this has on the grammar is that there are words and phrases which we can use in negative clauses that won't work so well in positive ones. These are usually called *negative polarity items*. So there are words and phrases we can use with sentence (2) that we can't use with sentence (1). Take for example the negative polarity items *either* or *at all*:

- *It's unwise to vote down this question either. (ungrammatical)
- It's not wise to vote down this question either.
- *It's unwise at all to vote down this question. (ungrammatical)
- It's not wise at all to vote down this question.

So although the meaning of sentences (1) and (2) is very similar, the grammar is completely different!

Comment: I can feel those 2 are wrong, but if I were asked to explain why, I can't. Can you? | Tenses are correct; sentence structure is correct; punctuation are placed at the right positions. What else that makes the 2 sentences wrong?